# How to move PDF files based on file name to folders with appropriate name?

Tags: batch-file

How to move PDF files by batch based on the file name to folders?

I have PDFs each beginning with different name and I want to move the PDF files to the folder with the appropriate name.

For example:

```
2-Net Ptd Ltd_xxxx.pdf
Transportation Services_xxxx.pdf
```

`2-Net Ptd Ltd` is the folder name for first file, `Transportation Services` is the folder name for second file.

How can I move `2-Net Ptd Ltd_xxxx.pdf` to the `2-Net Ptd Ltd` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This batch code moves all PDF files in current directory containing at least 1 underscore into a subfolder with name determined by string up to first underscore in file name.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1* delims=_" %%A in ('dir /B /ON *_*.pdf 2^>nul') do (
    md "%%A" 2>nul
    move /Y "%%A_%%B" "%%A"
)
```

Note: PDF files beginning with 1 or more underscores in file name are not moved and produce an error message on move. Also PDF files with more than one underscore on first occurrence of an underscore are not moved and produce an error message on move.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`

Comment: Hi, it's worked well.  Many appreciate of you help and get to more understand of how the function works :)